# Using a bitmap created in a private method in one class and using the bitmap in another class

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to display a bitmap image created in a method in one java class and show it in an ImageView in another java class. This is the code I have so far but I just get an empty ImageView. Can anyone tell me why?

Here's the code from my PictureLocation.java file (this is where the bitmap image I want to show in another activity is created)

```
// THIS IS WHERE THE BITMAP FILE IS GENERATED WHEN TAKING A PHOTO
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    // HERE I AM SETTING THE THUMBNAIL SO THAT I CAN GET IT LATER
    setBitmap(thumbnail);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // THIS IS THE ACTIVITY I NEED TO SHOW THE BITMAP IN
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageModification.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap image){
    this.myImage = image;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return this.myImage;
}
```

Here's the code for my ImageModification.java file. This is where I'm attempting to get the created bitmap file from the PictureLocation.java file and display it in an ImageView.

```
public class ImageModification extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView sourceImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_modification_layout);

    // ONCE THIS ACTIVITY IS STARTED I TRY TO DISPLAY THE BITMAP 
    // IN AN  IMAGEVIEW
    PictureLocation pictureLocation = new PictureLocation();
    sourceImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sourceImage);
    sourceImage.setImageBitmap(pictureLocation.getBitmap());
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asking how to make provide a reference created in a private method visible from somewhere else? If so, there are a lot of ways to do that: Pass the method a wrapper to a shared "container" object that can also be seen by the activity and put the image there, store it in a member field with publically-visible getter methods, have onCaptureImageResult call a public setter method for the activity to pass it the reference..

Comment: Since `thumbnail` is local to onCaptureImageResult(),goes out of scope as soon as that method ends. However, you set it as the image bitmap for `ivImage` (whatever that is, since you don't show where it is declared), so you can presumably retrieve it using getImageBitmap() if such a method exists, and if it can be retrieved from your other class.

Comment: I edited the question to show the code I have so far and also to clarify what it is I'm trying to do. Please have a look if you can. Thanks!